# Creating items via ajax force rails to create additional items in DB

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, zurb-foundation

I am using Foundation and Rails (I dont know why, but I think that problem in foundation).  When I create new comment for article, on first article I have one comment per click, as it have to be, but if I go to another article - its creates two similar comments, go to another article and I get 4 comments, then 7 and so on. I think that problem in Foundation, because it render errors in Browser:

Uncaught Error: jquery-ujs has already been loaded! and

Object [object Object] has no method 'foundation'

Tell me please how can I solve this problem

my model:

```
class Comment
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
  has_many :answers, as: :commentable, class_name: "Comment"

  default_scope queryable.order_by(:created_at.asc)


  field :body, type: String
  validates_presence_of :body


end
```

my controller action:

```
def create
@comment = @commentable.comments.new(params_comment)
if @comment.save
  flash.now[:notice] = "..."
  @response = {comment: @comment, model: @commentable}
  respond_with(@comment) { @response }
else
  flash.now[:alert] = "..."
  respond_with(@comment)
end
```

end

my create.js.coffee

```
$("<%= escape_javascript( render 'shared/comment', @response)%>").appendTo(".comments").hide().fadeIn(500)
```

and my view:

```
.comments
  =render "comment"
```

my partial:

```
.comment{ id: "comment-#{comment.id}"}
  = image_tag("delete/brian.jpg", class: "avatar")
  .comment-author
    =Faker::Name.name
    %time.comment-date= l comment.created_at
  .comment-text
    = comment.body
  -if comment.answers.any?
    .answers
      -comment.answers.each do |answer|
        .comments-answer
          =image_tag('delete/brian.jpg',class: "avatar")
          .comment-author
            =Faker::Name.name
            %time.comment-date= l(answer.created_at)
          .comment-text= answer.body
        = form_for([comment, Answer.new]) do |f|
          = f.text_area :body, rows: 8
          = f.submit 
  .wrapper
    = link_to 'Destroy', [model, comment], method: :delete, remote: true,class: "euro"
  %hr
```

form:

```
#comment_form
 = form_for([@article, @comment],:remote => true) do |f|
  = f.text_area :body, rows: 8
  = f.submit "Написать", class: "button small round"
```

Answer (score 0):

You likely are loading two copies of jquery causing both of these errors. Foundation includes it's own copy of jQuery by default. Just remove one of them, and it should clear up.

See also: https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/2125

Comment: Thanks, I've already read this post. But my problem is that I dont have any Jquery files in my projects directories(rails 4). So I dont know where from I should delete them

Comment: Look in your application.js file, rails includes jquery by default

Comment: thx for reply, I`ve solved this wuth removing jquery from manifest file, and including it in page just before foundation.